# how to fix infinite " " printing on While statement?

Tags: python

im trying to code this caesar cipher decoder, but whenever the input message has any " "(spaces) it just print " " infinitely
[ps: just started coding]

already tried to change -if- to check if meslist[x] is equal to " ", but it doesent seems like a "valid" thing

here is the code:

```
import string
letras = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
message = input("qual sua menssagem codificada?")
cod = input("qual a numeração da cifra?")
meslist = list(message)

trans = True
num = len(meslist)
x = 0
while trans:

if num > x:
    if meslist[x] in letras:
        a = letras.index(meslist[x])
        print(letras[a + 2])
        x = x + 1
        trans = True
    else:
        print(" ")
        trans = True
elif num == 0:
        trans = False'
```

just expecting for it to print it the right way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please fix your code's indentation. If everything is in fact inside the `while` block, the problem is that the block doesn't change the loop predicate, namely, `num == 0` will never be true (unless `x` started out < 0 and `meslist[x]` is always in `letras`). What is your expected come, specifically ("right way" is not really obvious)? Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: in `else:` you don't change `x = x + 1` so it never get next char. Maybe you should use `for char in message:` instead of `while` loop.

Comment: i just changed something i done wrong, it was supposed to be `elif x == 0` not "num"

and my expected result is to print " " everytime the input message has more than one word, like:

when input: g fmnc
output is:

i

h
o
p
e

Comment: the thing is that whenever there is a space between 2 words in Input, when the code runs, it just prints " " for ever

Comment: they close question so I put answer on https://pastebin.com/Za2SRHa3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code as below :

```
while trans:
    if num > x:
        if meslist[x] in letras:
            a = letras.index(meslist[x])
            print(letras[a + 2])
            x = x + 1
            trans = True
        else:
            print(" ")
            trans = True
            # to increase x by 1, to take the next char. in the next loop
            x = x + 1
    # num == x means the end of the loop
    elif num == x:
            trans = False
```

Comment: thanks a lot that was the mistake, x was increasing not decreasing, thanksss